# When I press ALT+CTRL+F1 it takes me to a blank screen

Tags: command-line, nvidia, screen, display-resolution, console

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on Nvidia Tegra K1 development kit and when I try to move to CLI by pressing ALT+CTRL+F1 (F2, F3, F4, F5 or F6) it take me to a black screen but when I change the resolution of the screen to 1024x768 it works just fine but it doesn't work on any other resolution.

I also tried connecting the development kit to a PC using a serial cable and on Putty it displays everything just fine on the PC but there is no display on the monitor to which the development kit is connected. I want to run the CLI at 1280x960.

The kit is connected to a VGA monitor through HDMI to a VGA converter.

Comment: It's unclear (at least to me) whether the monitor your using even supports 1280x960...